# Dart StreamController

Tags: dart

Hello i have a problem while using StreamController in Dart i have create afunction make a stream cntroller
Code:

```
dynamic main() {
  Future getData(String text) async {
    var stream;
    stream = StreamController();
    stream.stream.listen((text) {
      print(text);
    });
    stream.sink.add(text);
    stream.sink.close();
  }
  getData('hello stream');
  getData('hello stream');
}
```

When i create instance it works and i can't close stream
Output:

```
hello stream
hello stream
Exited
```

How can i close Stream

Comment: Could you try explain your problem in more details e.g. what did you expect to happen and what happens? I am rather unsure what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: When i make instance from this function it works but if i made another instance it work i dont want the second instance work i want the first instance work then close stream

Comment: But your are creating a new `Stream` inside the `getData` method which you are also closing. So the second time you are calling `getData` it will use another instance of `StreamController` with its own `Stream`.